# Integrating SAML authentication into Angular 14

Tags: angular, saml

We need use existing SAML based authentication for Angular 14 based application hosted on Azure cloud.

Can somebody suggest right package to be used for integration.
Also do share some code snippets if already implemented in any project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Frontend applications is not suitable for doing SAML authentication directly as it can not store private keys, needed by SAML, securly.

A typical way of doing it is to instead use a protocol suited for frontend, like OIDC, towards a backend that can then use SAML against the SAML IdP in Azure.

On my blog I have [written how to do this in ReactJs using Keycloak](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/saml-for-react-spa/) as backend, performing SAML communications.

If possible using OIDC directly in Azure would be preferable.